# Representing a multivariate normal with a scaled variance

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, linear-algebra

I would like to model an observation to have a multivariate normal distribution but am having some trouble figuring out the linear algebra.

So, let us start with a distribution that I know how to handle. 
$$
P(Y|X,A,V) = \prod_i p(y_i|x_i, A, V)
$$

Now modeling this as a multivariate normal distribution I get:

$$
\frac{1}{|2 \pi V|^\frac{N}{2}} \exp (-\frac{1}{2}\sum_i(y_i - Ax_i)^T V^{-1} (y_i - A x_i))
$$

where $Ax_i$ is the mean vector and $V^{-1}$ is the inverse covariance matrix. This can be written as:

$$
\frac{1}{|2 \pi V|^\frac{N}{2}} \exp (-\frac{1}{2}tr (V^{-1}(Y - AX)(Y - AX)^T))
$$

Here we utilise some trace identities and we concatenate all the $x_i$ and $y_i$. So if $Y$ and $X$ represent a $ 3 \times N$ entity (N points of dimension 3), $A$ and $V$ Are $3 \times 3$ matrix, we are finally taking the trace of a $3 \times 3$ matrix,  which is a scalar.

Now, I want to change the model slightly, in that each point has a scaling parameter for the variances. I think this is called the concentration parameter.

So, the distribution changes to: 
$$
P(Y|X,A,V) = \prod_i p(y_i|x_i, A, W_i^{-1}V)
$$

Now if I want to do a similar representation of this as with the other one. My first thought was that I could make a diagonal $W$ with all the weights along each of the dimension, which would make a $3N \times 3N$ matrix. It would be a diagonal matrix. Similarly, I could make a block diagonal structure for $V$ which would also be $3N \times 3N$. Also, I will need to augment the $X$ and $Y$ vector to be of size $3N \times N$ where the column vectors will be 0 pretty much everywhere, except the three values at the given index. Additionally, the matrix $A$ has to be augmented as well to be of size $3N \times 3N$ by imparting it a block matrix structure.

$$
\frac{1}{|2 \pi W^{-1}V|^\frac{N}{2}} \exp (-\frac{1}{2}tr (V^{-1}W(Y - AX)(Y - AX)^T))
$$

This, of course, makes it computationally expensive and now I have the $A$ matrix which is well, quite large and then if I want a prior on $A$, it also will be very high dimensional (the prior is a matrix normal)

So, I was wondering if there is another way to represent this? I was looking at trying to use kronecker product way but did not get very far. My initial attempt was to see if the matrix product $W^{-1}V$ could be represented by a chronicler product. With some simple tests in Octave, I realised it might not be possible to do so.

Comment: There are lots of errors in what you have written (e.g. the equation where you first introduce the trace, the modified distribution where you first mention $W$), and much unnecessary baggage too (e.g. $A$ and $X$ don't seem to be needed separately since the mean is always $AX$). When variances get scaled, it is not just the diagonal elements of $V$ that get scaled as you seem to think: _all_ entries in $V$ get scaled as $V_{i,j}\to W_i V_{i,j}W_j$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I will go through my post and try and correct it. Thank you very much for pointing this out. Of course, it is not just the diagonal elements that get scaled. $W$ here was meant to represent a diagonal matrix and perform matrix-matrix multiplication with $V$. Can you point me to where I perhaps have made this sound ambiguous or incorrect?

Comment: Thank you very much for clarifying this. I will go through this post properly again and try and correct as many mistakes that I can understand. Sorry for the mistakes but it was my lack of understanding of this rather than sloppiness.

Comment: Also, did you mean $WV$ multiplies all entries in the i-th *row* of V by $W_i$?

Comment: If $W$ is a diagonal matrix, then $WV$ multiplies all entries in the i-th row of $V$ by $W_i$. This is not entirely what is wanted: the $j$-th entry in the $i$-th row needs to be multiplied by $W_j$, not just by $W_i$ (which we have taken care of via $WV$). In short, you need $WVW^T$ to get the correct covariance matrix after scaling.